# ActiveMQ: Compression setting ignored

Tags: compression, activemq-classic

For some reason I can not get ActiveMQ to deliver compressed messages.
The messages are definitely uncompressed. I confirmed this with a sniffer. 
"setUseCompression" is definitely "true". I read this back and log it.

The client is 5.9. The server is 5.6 (Is this maybe the problem?)
The URI is of the form tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:61000

Code snippet:

```
        connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(usr, pwd, uri);
        connectionFactory.setOptimizeAcknowledge(true);
        connectionFactory.setOptimizeAcknowledgeTimeOut(1000);
        connectionFactory.setUseCompression(compressionEnabled);
        connectionFactory.setClientID(queueClientID); 

        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        if (!connectionFactory.isUseCompression())
            logger.warn("Compression is not enabled for activeMQ session");
        else 
            logger.info("Compression is enabled for activeMQ session");
```

Ideas anyone?
Tx

Comment: Need more context on the problem.  What is your evidence that compression is not enabled?

Comment: Keep in mind that reading the message via the web console will uncompress it, if you're doing that.

Comment: Got suspicious about it doing back-of-envelope bandwidth usage calculation. Then I used "nast" to sniff the network traffic on Ubuntu. I know what the payload looks like (xml) and it was clearly visible (uncompressed) in the nast output.

Comment: Size of the uncompressed messages are between 2k and 3k bytes.

Comment: Attach a debugger and step through the sending code.  A great place to put a breakpoint would be the `storeContent()` method of the appropriate ActiveMQ*Message (depending on what message type you're using).